# Is it possible to do this with only CSS, no JavaScript?

Tags: html, css

An outline of the scenario is that I have a `div` of class `some-class` which will either have 1 or 2 child `div`s. Whenever it has 1 I want that child div (`div.some-class > div`) to have `width: 100%;`, but whenever it has 2 I want them (`div.some-class > div:nth-of-type(1), div.some-class > div:nth-of-type(2)`) to have respective widths of `60%` and `40%`. I can't modify the HTML because it's generated by a content management system.

Is there a CSS hack that could give me this behavior?

Comment: Nope, you are dealing with dynamic behavior here. Best thing is to create separate rules in CSS and simply apply them through JavaScript

Comment: @beautifulcoder Dynamic behavior doesn't require javascript; responsive design is often done through CSS alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, use `display: table` and the [**adjacent sibling selector**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors).

```css
body > div {
    display: table;
    width: 600px;
}

div > div {
    background: blue;
    height: 100px;
    display: table-cell;
}

div > div + div {
    background: red;
    width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div></div>
</div>

<hr>

<div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```